# Querying the DOM using jQuery, code not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is really strange and I checked the jQuery API just to make sure things have not changed since the tutorial was created.

However the above code still gives me all the child elements, which are I am first, You are second and Hello from the nest instead of the first element.

```js
$('ul.emphasis').children('li').first().addClass('emphasis');
```

```css
.emphasis {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Welcome to my website</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus suscipit rem quibusdam sapiente obcaecati unde quod sed? Veritatis, laudantium? Ullam aliquid, rem ipsum cupiditate non repellendus culpa consequatur incidunt, perspiciatis!</p>


  <ul class="emphasis">
    <li>I am first</li>
    <li>YOu are second</li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>Hello from the nest</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: At least put some effort in formatting your question. Also it should be pretty obvious what is happening.

Comment: Are you sure you thought this through? What are your expectations when the class you are adding is already on the parent?

Comment: what? I am selecting an element and trying to add the css class to it.

Comment: and the code works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/6xoav46m/

Comment: use `li.emphasis` in your CSS

Comment: The class _does_ get added to the first LI element in your selection only (as a simply look with the browser’s DOM inspector would have already shown you) – but since the UL has the same class, all of it’s text content gets red text color … D’oh!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is behaving as you originally expected it to, in that the result of `.first()` is returning only the `li` element containing the text `"I am first"`. The reason all of the elements appear red when you open this in a browser is that you are reusing the class `emphasis` for both the parent and the child. Since `color` and `font-weight` are inherited CSS attributes all of the `li` elements under `ul.emphasis` are going to be red and bold. But like I said, only the first `li` element has the `emphasis` class.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am new to programming and without stackoveflow I would have given up on the whole tutorial series. I hope the question is not deleted and I not blocked.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that ALL of your text is red is because you apply the `color: red` rule to your parent `ul`.  This means that ALL of your content INSIDE the `ul` will be red.  Your first `li` IS recieving the `.emphasis` class, but it would be red without that class anyway.  To change your code, use `class="emphasized"` on the `ul`, then change the selector in the jQuery to `$('ul.emphasized')`.

Here's a working version of your code:

```js
$('ul.emphasized').children('li').first().addClass('emphasis');
```

```css
.emphasis {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Welcome to my website</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus suscipit rem quibusdam sapiente obcaecati unde quod sed? Veritatis, laudantium? Ullam aliquid, rem ipsum cupiditate non repellendus culpa consequatur incidunt, perspiciatis!</p>


  <ul class="emphasized">
    <li>I am first</li>
    <li>YOu are second</li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>Hello from the nest</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You simply need to use a different class for the parent selector and adding the actual styling.

```js
$('ul.emphasize').children('li').first().addClass('emphasis');
```

```css
.emphasis {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Welcome to my website</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus suscipit rem quibusdam sapiente obcaecati unde quod sed? Veritatis, laudantium? Ullam aliquid, rem ipsum cupiditate non repellendus culpa consequatur incidunt, perspiciatis!</p>


  <ul class="emphasize">
    <li>I am first</li>
    <li>YOu are second</li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>Hello from the nest</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is this answer down voted? I accept I could have done so more research but when you are new to programming its hard to notice things like this. I could have given up on a jquery tutorial series if it wasn't for this and the answer above.